# ASP.NET 5: Is localization with DisplayAttribute gone?

Tags: localization, data-annotations, asp.net-core

I am migrating an application from previous ASP.NET version to ASP.NET 5(vNext, MVC 6). Previously I localized forms with `DisplayAttribute` attached to ViewModel's properties:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation))]
[Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Common))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I added DataAnnotations service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/Views")
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

When I submit an invalid form, an error message gets localized (as specified in the `[Required]` attribute).

But trying to display the form, I got an exception (No public property "UserName" in the resource class), until I commented out `[Display]` attribute.

Seems like input labels can't be localized with `[DisplayAttribute]` anymore?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a resx file? Can you include that in your post as well?

Comment: Yes, .resx file ia s part of the asp.net website project. I created a paste with it's content (as xml): http://pastebin.com/7h1Vhu7s. Generated class indeed has `internal` access modifiers (and I can't change it in a ASP.NET 5 project), but it works for validation error messages.

Comment: It should work if you manually change the generated class' modifier to `public`. Keep an eye on this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/31) well as it's related to your question.

Comment: So how should we work around this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833661

Comment: @nativehr can you give an example of how did you manage to get this working with the ErrorMessage-s?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed gone. According to the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#dataannotations-localization):

> The runtime doesn’t look up localized strings for non-validation attributes. In the code above, “Email” (from [Display(Name = "Email")]) will not be localized.

**Update 20.03.2017**:

Localization of non-validation attributes was re-enabled with the new .NET Core SDK, according to the [updated documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#dataannotations-localization):

> DataAnnotations error messages are localized with `IStringLocalizer<T>`.
>   Using the option `ResourcesPath = "Resources"`, the error messages in `RegisterViewModel` can be stored in either of the following paths:
>
> - Resources/ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel.fr.resx
> - Resources/ViewModels/Account/RegisterViewModel.fr.resx